# Cómo verificar que un número que se ingresa sea estrictamente entero

Tags: c++

estoy realizando un programa donde valido que el número que se está ingresando por consola sea entero, con la finalidad de decirle al usuario si este es entero o no.

```
int main(){
 int num=0;
  cout<<"ingrese un numero para determinar si es entero o no"<<endl;
 cin>>num;
 if(num < 0){
  cout<<"el numero que ingreso"<<num<< "no es entero"<<endl;
 }else cout<<"el numero que ingreso "<<num<<" es entero"<<endl;
 return 0;
}
```

El problema que surge, es que si de entrada coloca por ejemplo: 10.5, me dice:

el número que ingresó **10** es entero

cómo evito que esto pase al colocar números con decimales? ya que debería decirme que el número no es entero
Pd: apenas estoy aprendiendo, disculpen si tengo algún error en el código